# Problem building rosjava_core and android_core (couldn't find install_generated_modules.py)

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build rosjava_core and android_core from source.  Here are the steps I've tried:

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/rosjava rosjava_core
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/rosjava.android android_core
```

From http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/building.html

```
roscd rosjava_core
./gradlew install

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 mins 13.005 secs
```

From http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/building.html

```
roscd android_core
rosrun rosjava_bootstrap install_generated_modules.py android_tutorial_pubsub

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named install_generated_modules.py below /home/brandonb/ros_android3/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap
```

I looked in the rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap directory and there is no scripts directory where the install_generated_modules.py used to be.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31108/problem-building-rosjava_core-and-android_core-(couldn%27t-find-install_generated_modules.py)/) by [bblodget](https://answers.ros.org/users/1939/bblodget/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The person in charge of rosjava and rosjava.android updated rosjava with some significant internal changes yesterday, however has not updated the android portion.  My guess is that you will need to use the previous version of rosjava until he does...

---

Originally posted by [Jyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2115/jyo/) with karma: 100 on 2012-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bblodget](https://answers.ros.org/users/1939/bblodget/) on 2012-04-03**:
Thanks.  Do you have a suggestion for what previous version I should try?  I tried change set 954:ff50a6891058 from March 14th but ./gradlew install failed.

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-04-03**:
android_core and the associated documentation have been updated and build correctly again.

**Comment by [bblodget](https://answers.ros.org/users/1939/bblodget/) on 2012-04-04**:
Great!  I have android_core building successfully now.  I also had to "hg clone https://code.google.com/p/rosjava.google rosjava_google" and run "gradlew install" on that because I was getting an error about "compressed_visualization_transport_msgs does not exist" during the android_core build.